# GitLab CI run docker container of other Repository

Tags: docker, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

I am generally still relatively new to the GitLab CI topic and unfortunately I cannot test this myself yet, so this is more of a theoretical attempt.
I want to start a Docker container from one of my other projects in Gitlab in the CI pipeline of my main project.
This Container (I now call it Mock-Container) is created and published in the GitLab CI pipeline of the corresponding project and contains various mocked services.
In the project in which I want to run the Mock-Container, it should be able to start that container in the GitLab CI.

I know it is possible to use a build of the project in a different stage in the same pipeline, like here for example:

```
variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2376
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
  CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
  CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
```

is it for example possible if the $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE used in CONTAINER-IMAGE-Variables is like:

```
registry.gitlab.com/foo/bar/mainproject
```

to add a variable here like:

```
MOCK_CONTAINER_IMAGE: registry.gitlab.com/foo/bar/mockproject:latest
```

so I could for example could use it in the services list in the test stage:

```
build:
  stage: build
  image: quay.io/podman/stable
  script:
    - podman login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY --log-level=debug
    - podman build --format docker --pull -t $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE .
    - podman push $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE

test:
  stage: test
  image:
    name: postman/newman
    entrypoint: [ "" ]
  services:
    - name: $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
      alias: main-project
    - name: $MOCK_CONTAINER_IMAGE
      alias: mock-container
  ...
```

Is this possible or is there a better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking that you want to set a variable in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file with the registry URL of the other container like this:

```yaml
variables:
  MOCK_CONTAINER_IMAGE: registry.gitlab.com/foo/bar/mockproject:latest
```

then yes you can. And you can use the variable in different stages in your file as you please. If you want to pull this image here from the registry, you can do that in a stage as well.

Check this reference for more info: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#variables

Comment: yes as i said it was a more theoretical attempt and so this was exactly what I wanted to know, thank you!